# Как найти все результаты регулярного выражения без переноса строки

Tags: php7

Подскажите почему мое регулярное выражение не видит второе определение текста, однако если перенести строку, то определяет. Можно ли составить выражение так, чтобы определял второй текст без переноса строки?

Регулярное выражение: /(.+)</th>/

`<th style="width:500px">`Количество ответов`</th><th>`% ответов`</th>`

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо использовать более жадный вариант:

```
<?php
    preg_match_all("|<th.*>([\s\S]*)<\/th>|U",
        "<th>example: </th><th align=left>this блабла is a test</th>",
        $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    print_r($out);
?>
```

результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <th>example: </th>
            [1] => <th align=left>this блабла is a test</th>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => example: 
            [1] => this блабла is a test
        )

)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду вникать)